# How do I regenerate the build directory in my Remix project to fix persistent 404 errors for removed assets and routes in Remix Project

Tags: javascript, typescript, deployment, remix.run

I'm encountering a persistent issue with 404 errors for various assets and routes when running my remix application. The server starts successfully but when I try visiting any route, I get this

```
[1]  Rebuilt in 17.5s
[1] Remix App Server started at http://localhost:3000
[1] No routes matched location "/build/_assets/inter-IWJQFSCC.css" 
[1] No routes matched location "/build/_assets/tailwind-TWWQ2DUC.css" 
[1] GET /build/_assets/inter-IWJQFSCC.css 404 - - 250.955 ms
[1] No routes matched location "/images/homebanner1.png" 
[1] No routes matched location "/images/productsIconAcademy.png" 
[1] GET /build/_assets/tailwind-TWWQ2DUC.css 404 - - 93.307 ms
[1] No routes matched location "/build/entry.client-KPVOLNQD.js" 
[1] No routes matched location "/build/_shared/chunk-LQ53JVGW.js" 
[1] No routes matched location "/build/_shared/chunk-VVZ2OONF.js" 
[1] GET /images/productsIconAcademy.png 404 - - 104.926 ms
[1] GET /images/homebanner1.png 404 - - 223.806 ms
[1] GET / 200 - - 9622.168 ms
[1] GET /build/entry.client-KPVOLNQD.js 404 - - 157.002 ms
[1] GET /build/_shared/chunk-LQ53JVGW.js 404 - - 81.498 ms
[1] No routes matched location "/build/_shared/chunk-FCC3XGIV.js" 
[1] No routes matched location "/build/_shared/chunk-P3MTAGQC.js" 
[1] GET /build/_shared/chunk-VVZ2OONF.js 404 - - 52.430 ms
[1] No routes matched location "/build/_shared/chunk-5H7MUHQN.js" 
[1] No routes matched location "/build/_shared/chunk-4YH5QKA4.js" 
[1] No routes matched location "/build/_shared/chunk-JN2YKU7I.js"
[1] GET /build/_shared/chunk-5H7MUHQN.js 404 - - 164.475 ms
[1] No routes matched location "/build/_shared/chunk-A6FEB3ZR.js" 
[1] No routes matched location "/build/_shared/chunk-Y3DLRQOV.js" 
[1] GET /build/_shared/chunk-FCC3XGIV.js 404 - - 248.913 ms
[1] GET /build/_shared/chunk-P3MTAGQC.js 404 - - 158.872 ms
[1] GET /build/_shared/chunk-4YH5QKA4.js 404 - - 128.397 ms
[1] GET /build/_shared/chunk-JN2YKU7I.js 404 - - 44.209 ms
[1] No routes matched location "/build/_shared/chunk-YCDCR5B6.js" 
[1] GET /build/_shared/chunk-A6FEB3ZR.js 404 - - 38.639 ms
[1] No routes matched location "/build/_shared/chunk-EKMIKQN3.js" 
[1] (node:8176) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added to [Commander]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
[1] (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created) 
[1] GET /build/_shared/chunk-YCDCR5B6.js 404 - - 138.531 ms
[1] No routes matched location "/build/_shared/chunk-UK6VKDVF.js" 
[1] No routes matched location "/build/_shared/chunk-ZU3LXG3W.js" 
[1] GET /build/_shared/chunk-Y3DLRQOV.js 404 - - 99.970 ms
[1] No routes matched location "/build/_shared/chunk-GT5AZVGV.js" 
[1] No routes matched location "/build/root-YQBWFN2X.js" 
[1] No routes matched location "/build/_shared/chunk-HDZBUZPC.js" 
[1] GET /build/_shared/chunk-EKMIKQN3.js 404 - - 136.365 ms
[1] GET /build/_shared/chunk-UK6VKDVF.js 404 - - 226.863 ms
[1] GET /build/_shared/chunk-ZU3LXG3W.js 404 - - 104.995 ms
[1] GET /build/_shared/chunk-GT5AZVGV.js 404 - - 154.139 ms
[1] GET /build/root-YQBWFN2X.js 404 - - 160.626 ms
[1] No routes matched location "/build/_shared/chunk-D3IE64NU.js" 
[1] No routes matched location "/build/_shared/chunk-E7WUZPEV.js" 
[1] No routes matched location "/build/_shared/chunk-F5JUPCFC.js" 
[1] GET /build/_shared/chunk-HDZBUZPC.js 404 - - 92.188 ms
[1] GET /build/_shared/chunk-D3IE64NU.js 404 - - 150.033 ms
[1] No routes matched location "/build/_shared/chunk-MQ4IJL2S.js" 
[1] GET /build/_shared/chunk-F5JUPCFC.js 404 - - 60.755 ms
[1] No routes matched location "/build/_shared/chunk-7Q3XY7UI.js" 
[1] No routes matched location "/build/routes/_hub-ECVEGFI4.js" 
[1] No routes matched location "/build/_shared/chunk-VDH3D5QX.js" 
[1] GET /build/_shared/chunk-7Q3XY7UI.js 404 - - 207.429 ms
[1] No routes matched location "/build/routes/_hub._index-CVXFV4E5.js" 
[1] GET /build/_shared/chunk-VDH3D5QX.js 404 - - 45.004 ms
[1] No routes matched location "/build/manifest-2B6FDE4F.js" 
[1] No routes matched location "/images/productsAcademy.png" 
[1] GET /build/_shared/chunk-E7WUZPEV.js 404 - - 170.042 ms
[1] GET /build/_shared/chunk-MQ4IJL2S.js 404 - - 181.242 ms
[1] No routes matched location "/images/productsIconJobs.png" 
[1] GET /build/routes/_hub-ECVEGFI4.js 404 - - 153.915 ms
[1] No routes matched location "/images/productsJobs.png" 
[1] GET /images/productsAcademy.png 404 - - 44.436 ms
[1] GET /build/routes/_hub._index-CVXFV4E5.js 404 - - 55.133 ms
[1] No routes matched location "/images/productsIconDirectory.png" 
[1] No routes matched location "/images/productsDirectory.png" 
[1] GET /images/productsIconJobs.png 404 - - 303.615 ms
[1] GET /build/manifest-2B6FDE4F.js 404 - - 146.677 ms
[1] No routes matched location "/images/productsIconNaaS.png" 
[1] No routes matched location "/images/productsNaaS.png" 
[1] GET /images/productsJobs.png 404 - - 172.249 ms
[1] GET /images/productsIconDirectory.png 404 - - 165.323 ms
[1] No routes matched location "/build/_assets/image%207-DJRB6VXT.png" 
[1] GET /images/productsDirectory.png 404 - - 165.177 ms
[1] No routes matched location "/build/_assets/image%2041-46I5YVJX.png" 
[1] No routes matched location "/build/_assets/image%2036-JJWRBVPR.png" 
[1] GET /images/productsNaaS.png 404 - - 72.335 ms
[1] GET /images/productsIconNaaS.png 404 - - 178.853 ms
[1] No routes matched location "/build/_assets/image%2035-N45T7ZJ3.png" 
[1] No routes matched location "/build/_assets/Rectangle%2015-NOFXM4AO.png" 
[1] GET /build/_assets/image%207-DJRB6VXT.png 404 - - 149.440 ms
[1] GET /build/_assets/image%2036-JJWRBVPR.png 404 - - 93.985 ms
[1] GET /build/_assets/image%2041-46I5YVJX.png 404 - - 191.468 ms
[1] GET /build/_assets/image%2035-N45T7ZJ3.png 404 - - 139.565 ms
[1] GET /build/_assets/Rectangle%2015-NOFXM4AO.png 404 - - 46.070 ms
```

These images are no longer present in the project, but the server continues to attempt to access them. This results in a nearly empty page with missing images, CSS, and JavaScript.

I tried deleting the build directory and restarting the server but the build directory isn't regenerated and I got a different error that the module *\build\index.js* is missing.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache? Seems like it's trying to load an older version of your app. You can also disable the cache from Dev Tools.

Comment: @Kiliman I haven’t. I’ll try that now

Comment: @Kiliman It didn’t work.

Comment: Hmm... seems really odd. Try creating a new project and moving your app folder over.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to resolve this by updating outdated dependencies then running yarn run remix build. Now the build directory is regenerated and the right files are added to the build directories

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this by updating outdated dependencies then running yarn run remix build. Now the build directory is regenerated and the right files are added to the build directories